# How this remote control generates radio signal?

Tags: rf, remote-control

I have this RF remote control that I'm trying to understand (here is spec: http://www.telran.co.il/images/980305%20QK-M04%20TECH%20SPECS.pdf ).

I recognize crystal oscillator that is responsible for getting required frequency of the signal, I understand how this hcs301 chip provides KeeLoq encryption, I recognize a battery as a power source ;) . But what here is actually generating the radio signal? I cannot find anything resembling an antenna here, and this remote has quite a long range (about 100m).

Could someone find an antenna here and explain what component(s) is responsible for generating an actual radio signal in this device?

[image: back]
[image: front #1]
[image: front #2]

Comment: At first glance, this appears to be an infrared remote rather than radio.  Note the LED (marked D3) at the end of the remote (opposite end to the crystal).

Comment: first picture, bottom trace appears to be the antenna

Comment: @DwayneReid It's radio one for sure, I'm using it to open my gate. :) and look at specs, the name of this model is actually also printed on PCB.

Comment: @jsotola This wider path? Actually it is indeed coming out of the oscillator so I think you got it, I didn't know antenna can look almost like a normal path.

Comment: "I didn't know antenna can look almost like a normal path" - and 'normal paths' don't usually look like antennas, but they often are (unintentionally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a 433 MHz oscillator, transistor "R25". The trace that likely radiates RF is around the perimeter, in yellow on the "bottom" side of the PCB:
[image]
The transistor collector is fed DC battery voltage through "L3" marked in yellow.